# Is there fallback strategy if user device or browser does not support vertex shaders of specific precision and ThreeJS crashes?

Tags: three.js, glsl, shader, precision

Our team facing more often than before with problem that may be related to wider spread of some (mobile?) devices that are already support (small or large) subset of WebGL.

Even browser vendors think it will work so don't blacklist that device/driver.

But problem is in deep internals of ThreeJS, where there is a line like this:

```js
a.getShaderPrecisionFormat(35633,36338)
```

that returns `null` unexpectedly. Like, device does not support combination of `WebGLRenderingContext.VERTEX_SHADER` and `WebGLRenderingContext.HIGH_FLOAT` respectively.
This is buried deeply into ThreeJS and this call can't be avoided, or I missed something?

Can ThreeJS be configured to find a fallback, like "feature detect" the best supported of HIGH_FLOAT, MEDIUM_FLOAT and LOW_FLOAT?

If so, will it seriously break shaders or its output? I am not a webgl specialist, sorry, so don't know whether they written with specific precision in mind - 32bit float, 64 double - or that mysterious MEDIUM_FLOAT.

Or I just must replicate the same check as a part of WebGL support detection flow and report to user at startup that not all webgl features supported and abandon actual app start?

Thank you very much for your time and answers.